# Is it possible to only give one argument to function with two parameters?

Tags: function, vue.js, parsing, parameters, arguments

I have kinda a wierd question. I'm working on removing redundance from my code, and I have two functions which are basically the same, except one of the functions have two parameters and the other one only have one.

I'm wondering if it's possible to "skip" one of the parameters when the function is called, in order to reduce redundance? The functions in this case is in VueJS. Here are the functions:

```
addTask: function (task, member) {
            if (task === '' || member === '') {
                alert ('Enter Task & Member!')
            } 
        }, 

addMember: function (addTeamMember) {
            if (addTeamMember === '') {
                alert ('Enter Name Of Team Member')
            }
```

So in other words, is it possible to call "addTask" and only parse one argument and skip the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by declaring the variable directly as you can do it in many other languages.

For example:

```
function addTask(task, member = "") {

}
```